# How to Wrap text widgets next to each other in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-text

[image]

Each number in between represents starting of a new widget. Is this possible in Flutter?.

Comment: that comes with second text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this bro

```
Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
  TextSpan(
     text: "... ١",
     recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
        ..onTap = () {}
  ),
  TextSpan(
     text: "... ٢",
     recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
        ..onTap = () {}
  ),
]), style: TextStyle(
  // ...
),)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but is this each TextSpan clickable?

Comment: Sure. I will check. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

yes its possible in flutter
you can use [Wrap widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

```
Wrap(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Text 1'),
    Text('Text 2'),
    Text('Text 3')
  ],
)
```